# How to shrink JSON string in ColdFusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, removing-whitespace

We are currently posting a JSON string to the Netsuite ERP platform using `cfhttp`. I'm noticing that when we post the data, we are getting a lot of weird errors. The majority of the errors contain unterminated string literal.  I've verified the JSON strings are completely perfect by running them through JSON lint and I'm noticing that the behavior from Netsuite is quite erratic.

Whilst doing some research, I've found that a lot of these unterminated string literal errors sometimes are related to white space. I'm noticing when I test my output, my code comes back with quite a lot of white space. I have some inline `<cfif>` statements which may also be the cause of some of this additional white space.

I'm wondering if there is any way to completely shrink any white space within a json string in ColdFusion? Is there a function that will clean up JSON strings so when I post them they suppress all white space ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you generating the JSON? Are you using `serializeJSON`? Showing the lines of code that generates and perform the HTTP request would be useful.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're building your JSON by hand... serializeJson() doesn't include any extraneous whitespace. Can you pls post some example code of how you're creating the JSON string, and also what the JSON looks like.

Comment: if you are generating JSON by hand, you may try using cfprocessingdirective suppressWhiteSpace=yes. However I would strongly recommend use same logic to create an object/struct and then convert it to JSON using serializeJson()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Enable Whitespace Management is checked in CFAdmin settings. This will reduce the whitespace returned to the browser from Coldfusion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @manetsus - Assuming the JSON is being generated by hand (seems likely), this is a valid suggestion on how to eliminate extra white space. Granted there are other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simple idea:

```
<cfset cfVar = DeserializeJSON(jsonWhithSpaces)>
<cfset jsonPure = SerializeJSON(cfVar)>
```